I keep getting errors while trying to add a tag description on MoviesSE
I was adding tag descriptions to those without description today on Movies&TV, and for every tag I got an error when I pressed Submit.

An error occurred submitting the post.

If I reload the page then I can Edit the description, and it gets submitted without error. (I don't have tag edit privileges, if that is relevant.)
I checked the browser console and it shows me an error 500. Could it be somewhat related to It is now impossible to make a suggested edit to a tag-info?
